# Parsing array of object Json in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm getting a JSON response as below

Enroll Status  -->{"data":[{"Id":"a082w000000YUH5AAO","EnrolStatus__c":"Submitted"}]}

How to read the object value in the response.( Always this will be a single object in an array);

```
@track enrollStatus;
 @wire(getEnrollmentStatus, {EnrollmentId: "$recordId" })
getenrollStatus(enrollstatus){
console.log('Enroll Status  -->' + JSON.stringify(enrollstatus))
 }



 public static List<Enrollment__c> getEnrollmentStatus(Id EnrollmentId) {          
    system.debug('ENROL ' + EnrollmentId);              
    return   [select  Id, EnrolStatus__c from Enrollment__c WHERE Id=:EnrollmentId];                
    }
```

Comment: Just directly e.g. `let name = enrollstatus.Name;` but note that names are case sensitive.

Comment: @KeithC
 
getenrollStatus(enrollstatus) {
    console.log("Enroll Status  -->" + JSON.stringify(enrollstatus));
    let enrollStatusvalue = enrollstatus.EnrolStatus__c;
     console.log('enrollStatus -->' + enrollStatusvalue);
}

Enroll Status  -->{"data":[{"Id":"a082w000000YUH5AAO","EnrolStatus__c":"Submitted"}]}
enrollStatus -->undefined

Comment: @KeithC , The above one is not working, Please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the data you've returned is already an object/array. The following should work:

```
console.log(enrollmentStatus.data[0].Id);
```

Unless you're using a plain string in the Apex return type, it will already be an object you can use directly.

Comment: Apex return type is list <object> public static List<Enrollment__c>

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read property 'EnrolStatus__c' of undefined`

Comment: var enrollstatusObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(enrollstatus)); console.log("enrollstatusObj -->" + enrollstatusObj[0].EnrolStatus__c);

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it as below. As you are sure, the result always will have a single value in the array inside response, You can get the [JavaScript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections) elements using index.

```
this.parsedValue = JSON.parse(enrollstatus);
console.log('this.parsedValue ' + this.parsedValue.data[0]);
console.log('this.parsedValue ' + this.parsedValue.data[0].Id);
console.log('this.parsedValue ' + this.parsedValue.data[0].EnrolStatus__c);
```

[image]

Parse the data with [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

Comment: Why wouldn't `enrollstatus` already be a JavaScript object? Otherwise why `JSON.stringify` it?

Comment: That's a question we should ask from @user3214361 to confirm it.

Comment: @sanketkumar Yes the result will be always single value in the array,

Comment: @sanketkumar I'm getting following error `Cannot read property 'EnrolStatus__c' of undefined` Please help on this.
var enrollstatusObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(enrollstatus));
console.log("enrollstatusObj -->" + enrollstatusObj[0].EnrolStatus__c);

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var enrollstatusObj = JSON.parse(enrollstatus);
var data = enrollstatusObj.data;
var id;
var enrollStatus;
if (data.length > 0) {
  id = data[o].Id;
  enrollStatus = data[0].EnrolStatus__c;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting following error `Cannot read property 'EnrolStatus__c' of undefined` Please help on this. var enrollstatusObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(enrollstatus)); console.log("enrollstatusObj -->" + enrollstatusObj[0].EnrolStatus__c);

Comment: @user3214361 There is no property `EnrolStatus__c` on `enrollstatusObj[0]`. You need to access the property using `var data = enrollstatusObj.data; // access property using data[o]. EnrolStatus__c ` Please check my answer again.

You'll have work on JavaScript mate.